# Firebase puppeteer PDF function times out due to Chrome revision

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, puppeteer, chromium

I have a Firebase function to create a PDF file. Lately, it times out due to a "Chrome revision"? Neither do I understand the error message, nor do I understand what is wrong. The function works, when I deploy it locally under MacOS.

```
TimeoutError: Timed out after 30000 ms while trying to connect to the browser! Only Chrome at revision r818858 is guaranteed to work.
    at Timeout.onTimeout (/workspace/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:204:20)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)
```

The function:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const createPDF = async (html, outputPath) => {

    let pdf;

    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            args: ['--no-sandbox']
        });
        const page = await browser.newPage();

        await page.emulateMediaType('screen');

        await page.setContent(html, {
            waitUntil: 'networkidle0'
        });

        pdf = await page.pdf({
           // path: outputPath,
            format: 'A4',
            printBackground: true,
            margin: {
                top: "50px",
                bottom: "50px"
            }
        });

        await browser.close();

    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }

    return pdf;
};
```

Comment: I'm having this as well. What version of Puppeteer are you using? Did the answer below work for you?

Answer (score 2):

> TimeoutError: Timed out after 30000 ms while trying to connect to the browser!

The aforementioned error is coming from the fact that as mentioned in the [documentation](https://pptr.dev/):

> When you install Puppeteer, it downloads a recent version of Chromium

Everytime you're executing Puppeteer you're running a Chromium in the backend to which Puppeteer will try to connect, hence when it can't connect to the browser this errors raises.

After doing multiple test I was able to execute the Cloud Function by adding the parameter `headless` on the launch option, since the documentation mentions that it should be `true` by default I don't quite understand why setting it manually allows the Cloud Function to finish correctly.
At the beginning I was trying with the `timeout` set to `0` to disable the error due to timeout, however it seems that it's not required, since by only adding `headless` it finished correctly, but if you find the same problem with the timeouts you can add it.
At the end my code looks like this:

```
const createPDF = async (html, outputPath) => {

    let pdf;

    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            args: ['--no-sandbox'],
            headless: true,
            timeout: 0
        });
        const page = await browser.newPage();

        await page.emulateMediaType('screen');

        await page.setContent(html, {
            waitUntil: 'networkidle0'
        });

        pdf = await page.pdf({
           // path: outputPath,
            format: 'A4',
            printBackground: true,
            margin: {
                top: "50px",
                bottom: "50px"
            }
        });

        await browser.close();
        console.log("Download finished"); //Added this to debug that it finishes correctly

    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }

    return pdf;
};
```