# can't load chrome driver with selenium, in the firebase cloud functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-cloud-functions

im trying use the chrome driver, with selenium in the firebase cloud functions.
while deploying the index.js file on to a local host, using the terminal cmd
'firebase serve --only functions' from the functions folder(which has the chromedriver file, every thing work like in supposed to, im getting a response.

But,
when I deploying the index.js file to the firebase real servers using the
'firebase deploy --only functions' ,

and then trigger the function from my app, or from a url,
im getting an error in the firebase cloud functions logs telling me
'Function execution took 1774 ms, finished with status: 'crash'  '

so since there were not details about what was causing this 'crash' I uses the consoled.log() function, and printed each line that was executed successfully.

[image]

this lead me into the line of

```
let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').setChromeOptions(new chrome.Options().headless().windowSize(screen)).build();
```

its seems like in the firebase cloud function I can't for some reason create a chrome driver successfully , although in the local host version, it's working as expected.

here the full code of the function:

```
exports.initializedChromeDriver = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  
    async function start_chrome_driver() {
        functions.logger.info('Hello logs!', {structuredData: true});
        console.log("did enter the function")
        const dic = {};
        const google_site = "https://www.gooogle.com"; 
        const { WebDriver } =  require('selenium-webdriver');
        const {Builder, By} = require('selenium-webdriver');
        console.log("did creat WebDriver,Builder, By, constans")
        const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
        console.log("chrome constans was created")
        const screen = {
          width: 1024,
          height: 1024
        };
        let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').setChromeOptions(new chrome.Options().headless().windowSize(screen)).build();
        console.log("driver was set");
        await driver.get(google_site);
        console.log("succ loading google");
        return "succ loading google"

     }
        const p = start_chrome_driver().then((value,reject) => {
            dic['status'] = 200;
            dic['data'] = {"message": value};
            response.send(dic);
        });
```

and here are the logs in the firebase cloud console:

[image]

**UPDATE**

well after searching for answers in the web, ,i found that I didn't have a suitable 'driver' for linux systems,
so I replace the chrome driver for mac(which work on my machine, on the local host version),
with a chrome driver, for linux. and try again, well that doesn't work either , but at lest I was getting a new log with an Error, not just a 'crash' , here it his:

[image]

so now I know that I need to install the chrome browser binary for linux on the project,
any ideas to how can I do this, Im trying to install the chrome binary driver on to my project in firebase, there a few ways im trying now, like installing the chrome binary using the google shell some how, any help or idea to I do does, even so, I don't sure that after the binary will be install , this will be it, and the driver will work on the firebase servers..

Comment: Afaik Headless chrome isn't supported on Cloud Functions, however [Pupeteer](https://pptr.dev/) does work, so if it suits your needs probably is the way to look into

Comment: i didn't know that, I thought that if I will get the path right, it will work eventually, good to know there are other options beside that, I will try Pupeteer  instead.  you been very helpful , tnx :)

Comment: another question, if I may... in the page , its says that "Puppeteer is a Node library which provides a high-level API to control Chrome or Chromium over the DevTools Protocol. Puppeteer runs headless by default, but can be configured to run full (non-headless) Chrome or Chromium."   -----> that means that Im still in need to install the chrome binary in and provide a path for it?

Comment: No, Pupeteer installs Chromium for you, just make sure to add the --headless tag as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66444996/5495197)